# createNewFile() Throws FileNotFoundException When Given the Correct FilePath

Tags: java, filepath

Here is my code below:

```
public void playerNaming() throws IOException {
      Scanner pickName = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("What do you want your username to be?");
      String playerName = pickName.nextLine();
      userName = playerName;
      File file1 = new File("PlayerFiles\\" + playerName + ".txt");
      File file2 = new File(file1.getAbsolutePath());
      System.out.println(file2);
      file2.createNewFile();
      BufferedWriter file3 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file2));
}
```

On line `file2.createNewFile();` It throws

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Insert correct FilePath here) The system cannot find the path specified**

What is wrong? According to all the articles and other stackoverflow questions I have read, this should work.

Comment: I suggest you print out the absolute path you've constructed and see if it is actually correct.

Comment: I have. It is correct.

Comment: Why do you need three file objects to write a single file? What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: @Seb, I am new to creating files in java, I thought you needed a new one for every step of the process.

Comment: Your code is overly complicated, try to simplify it and use absolute path, like this "C:\User...file.txt"

Comment: @Dennis Kozevnikoff, I am creating a program that I hope will one day be used by other people, so I need a way to create the file no matter where the other person stores the program.

Comment: In general something like 
File targetFile = new File(fileName);
        try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile)) {
            fileOutputStream.write(/*insert content here */);
}
should do the trick.

Comment: Also have a look here:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-filewriter#2-writing-a-stringto-a-file
or 
https://www.baeldung.com/java-how-to-create-a-file

Comment: @Seb, it says ```fileOutputStream.write()``` isn't applicable to the arguments ```(String)```

Comment: fileOutputStream.write(string.getBytes()).
Or use FileWriter instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your file path :

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
  
        try { 
  
            // Get the file 
            File f = new File("F:\\program1.txt"); 
  
            // Create new file 
            // if it does not exist 
            if (f.createNewFile()) 
                System.out.println("File created"); 
            else
                System.out.println("File already exists"); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { 
            System.err.println(e); 
        }
```

Note : The file “F:\program.txt” is a existing file in F: Directory.